# How can I output csv of groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I get the follow data with code :

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'ID': ['H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6'],
      'AA1': ['C','B','B','X','G','G'],
      'AA2': ['W','K','K','A','B','B'],
      'name':['n1','n2','n3','n4','n5','n6']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.groupby('AA1').apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('name'))
```

The ouput:

```
        AA1 AA2 ID  name
AA1                 
B   1   B   K   H2  n2
    2   B   K   H3  n3
C   0   C   W   H1  n1
G   4   G   B   H5  n5
    5   G   B   H6  n6
X   3   X   A   H4  n4
```

When I try to `to_csv` it will lose the first index `AA1`,I hope I can output the csv just like the `groupby` result but not the result like this:

```
    AA1 AA2 ID  name
1   B   K   H2  n2
2   B   K   H3  n3
0   C   W   H1  n1
4   G   B   H5  n5
5   G   B   H6  n6
3   X   A   H4  n4
```

I mean ,when I open the csv file in `excel` I hope can see the format like the output in jupyter!

Comment: Unfortunately, when saving, you cannot specify the index, but you can when loading: `index_col = [1, 0]`

Comment: So ,it's saying that if I want my data like groupby result in excel ,I  need to do it in Excel software?

Comment: Due to the limitations of excel and csv, when saving, it will not show as a multi-index. It's your job to load it into pandas as a multi index. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try this:

```
df_result.to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

And the index name "AA1" will be remained.

Comment: Yeah!Thanks for your help,maybe my question is not that clear and mislead and you make it work！

Answer (score 4):

CSV formats have its limitations. One of them being keeping information about multi-indexes. You will have to keep track and judiciously load your data. Here's an example.

```
df

      AA1 AA2  ID name
AA1                   
B   1   B   K  H2   n2
    2   B   K  H3   n3
C   0   C   W  H1   n1
G   4   G   B  H5   n5
    5   G   B  H6   n6
X   3   X   A  H4   n4

df.to_csv('test.csv')

!cat test.csv
AA1,,AA1,AA2,ID,name
B,1,B,K,H2,n2
B,2,B,K,H3,n3
C,0,C,W,H1,n1
G,4,G,B,H5,n5
G,5,G,B,H6,n6
X,3,X,A,H4,n4
```

That's how the CSV is saved. Now, when loading it back, specify `index_col` and the multi-index will be loaded as before.

```
(pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=[0, 1])
   .rename_axis(['AA1', None])
   .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.')[0]))

      AA1 AA2  ID name
AA1                   
B   1   B   K  H2   n2
    2   B   K  H3   n3
C   0   C   W  H1   n1
G   4   G   B  H5   n5
    5   G   B  H6   n6
X   3   X   A  H4   n4
```

Keep in mind that your column names are mangled when saving and re-loading - this is another CSV limitation.

As the other answer mentions, it would be better to explicitly save with an `index_label` when calling `to_csv` so you don't have to unmangle your columns.

Answer (score 2):

If want same output as before - MultiIndex DataFrame, need parameter `index_col` for create `MultiIndex` from first and second column:

```
df = pd.read_cav(file, index_col=[0,1])
```

Better is specify in `to_csv` parameter `index_label` for avoid duplicates index and columns names - here `AA1`:

```
df.to_csv('a.csv', index_label=['a','b'])
a,b,AA1,AA2,ID,name
B,1,B,K,H2,n2
B,2,B,K,H3,n3
C,0,C,W,H1,n1
G,4,G,B,H5,n5
G,5,G,B,H6,n6
X,3,X,A,H4,n4


df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', index_col=[0,1])
print (df)
    AA1 AA2  ID name
a b                 
B 1   B   K  H2   n2
  2   B   K  H3   n3
C 0   C   W  H1   n1
G 4   G   B  H5   n5
  5   G   B  H6   n6
X 3   X   A  H4   n4
```

Because by default get `Unnamed` for all columns without names and for all duplicates columns are added `.1`, `.2` for avoid duplicates:

```
df.to_csv('a.csv')
AA1,,AA1,AA2,ID,name
B,1,B,K,H2,n2
B,2,B,K,H3,n3
C,0,C,W,H1,n1
G,4,G,B,H5,n5
G,5,G,B,H6,n6
X,3,X,A,H4,n4

#create DataFrame without MultiIndex 
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
print (df)
  AA1  Unnamed: 1 AA1.1 AA2  ID name
0   B           1     B   K  H2   n2
1   B           2     B   K  H3   n3
2   C           0     C   W  H1   n1
3   G           4     G   B  H5   n5
4   G           5     G   B  H6   n6
5   X           3     X   A  H4   n4

#create DataFrame with Multiindex
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', index_col=[0,1])
print (df)
               AA1.1 AA2  ID name
AA1 Unnamed: 1                   
B   1              B   K  H2   n2
    2              B   K  H3   n3
C   0              C   W  H1   n1
G   4              G   B  H5   n5
    5              G   B  H6   n6
X   3              X   A  H4   n4
```

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, you don't need to use `.groupby` with `.sort_values`; `df.sort_values(['AA1','name'])` essentially does the same thing. So I would suggest the following, which doesn't exactly answer your question but might be a preferable alternative:

```
df.sort_values(['AA1','name']).to_csv('test.csv', index = False)
```

`index = False` here tells pandas not to write the index to the csv (the numbers from 0 to 5, reordered from the sorting). If you want that anyway, don't pass `index = False` to `.to_csv()`.